# Not able to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 in my system but i'm not able to connect to the same from my colleague's machine which is on the same network.

Firewall is off on both systems.

Edited:

I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 in my system the same installation is present in my colleague's system. While trying to connect to my machine from his machine using SQL Server Management studio it was showing an error as follows..
(I've used the server name for SQL management studio of my system for login)

[The server was not found or was not accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaHBA.png)

I found a solution to this problem after posting the question but not sure if this is the correct way.

The SQL Server Browser service was stopped when i tried to connect initially. Now when i start this service from Sql server configuration Manager i'm able to connect to my machine from his machine.

Comment: It would be a lot useful if you share the error message received. Connect with what?

Answer (score -1):

1-Install SQL Server (Management Studio) on both machines
2-On your machine, run SQL Server 
3-Make sure the server name is your colleague's machine IP address
4-enjoy!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen as if this was an "extra-detailed" question!!

Comment: @MincongHuang How will you connect from SQL server to another Sql server on another machine? it is clear the guy is not trying to connect to SQL server through some code, he just can't login to the server itself!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen repeating the same thing Steve did is useful? LOL

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen he never talked about any programming, he was talking about machines! the question is too simple for you to understand may be!

Comment: @MincongHuang That's what I meant, SQL Server Management Studio!

Comment: @Medo, I think you need to be more precise. SQL Server has components like SQL Server Database Engine, Integration Services, Analysis Services, Reporting Services, SQL Agent, Management Studio.

Comment: @MincongHuang Done!